# Trying to change formula of a specified cell when a different specified cell is edited

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to change the value of a particular cell, but only when a different particular cell is edited, in order to create a change of date calculation.

I'm really new to this, so not sure exactly what I'm doing.

```
function onEdit(e) {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
if(sheet.getName() === 'Date Calculator' && e.sheet.getRange() === 'C9' ) 
{
var cell = sheet.getRange("C10");
cell.setFormula('=WORKDAY(C9,+$C$3)');

    }
}
```

Nothing is happening, no errors.

```
[19-07-09 16:13:10:402 BST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange() [0 seconds]
[19-07-09 16:13:10:402 BST] Range.getRow() [0 seconds]
[19-07-09 16:13:10:402 BST] Range.getLastRow() [0 seconds]
[19-07-09 16:13:10:402 BST] Range.getColumn() [0 seconds]
[19-07-09 16:13:10:402 BST] Range.getLastColumn() [0 seconds]
[19-07-09 16:13:10:402 BST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[19-07-09 16:13:10:414 BST] Starting execution
[19-07-09 16:13:10:420 BST] Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[19-07-09 16:13:10:488 BST] Execution failed: ReferenceError: "sheet" is not defined. (line 4, file "Code") [0.002 seconds total runtime]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem:

Currently you're defining your **spreadsheet** rather than the **sheet**, then calling `setFormula()` on the spreadsheet object, you need to define the sheet and call `setFormula()` for that instead.

Also, `e.sheet.getRange()` is not possible, you should be using `e.range.getA1Notation()` to return 'C9' like you're expecting.

---

#### Solution:

Your code should look something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if(sh.getName() === 'Date Calculator' && e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C9' ) 
  {
    var cell = sh.getRange("C10");
    cell.setFormula('=WORKDAY(C9,+$C$3)');
  }
}
```

---

#### References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [`getA1Notation()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getA1Notation())

Comment: Thanks for the super swift response. Unfortunately I'm getting an error and still no functionality when I change the cell:

"TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 3, file "Code")"

Comment: Is this running onEdit, do you definitely have the (e) in the function name? Usually that error occurs when you try to run the script manually.

Comment: Yes sorry - so the error is coming up when I run manually/try debugging, but changing the C9 cell in the sheet doesn't then update the C10 cell, so I wasn't sure if I'm still missing something somewhere.

Comment: Make sure your sheet name is correct - also could you add your Execution Transcript to the question - edit the cell C9 then go to `View > Execution transcript` in the script editor to find this.

Comment: Sheet name is definitely correct (copy/pasted to be sure). Transcript added.

Comment: @DavidJenkins this was my fault - I changed `var sheet` to `var sh` and forgot to change the `if` statement to reflect this - try the revised code in my answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! 

Hopefully I can go from here and get it to do similar things elsewhere in the sheet. 

If I wanted it to complete TWO functions, would I just add another couple of lines after the IF? Like:

var cell = sh.getRange("C10");
    cell.setFormula('=WORKDAY(C9,+$C$3)');
var cell = sh.getRange("C8");
    cell.setFormula('=WORKDAY(C9,-$C$3)');

Or would I need to define multiple variables?

Comment: Yeah that would work - to be honest you don't even need `var cell` at all, you can just call `sh.getRange("C8").setFormula("yourFormulaHere")`.

Comment: If I wanted to make different changes based on editing a different cell, do I need a new function, or can I just add another IF statement?

Comment: @DavidJenkins you could add another `if`, or an `else if` to follow your current `if` statement. If you have loads of cell combinations then a `switch` statement is probably your most efficient option.

Comment: Awesome I'll look up how Switch statements function in Sheets, but I THINK I've got a handle on it now. Thank you again!